# Expand / Override parent's method in constructor filter

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I'm working on a WordPress project. There is a child theme implemented, and the parent one has a class to show authors' links. We have implemented a feature to support multiple authors per post, then we have our own methods for showing the proper links (not a single-author link, but many links joined depending on the authors count).

The complete scenario:

- Theme: Newspaper
- File: td_module.php (includes/wp_booster/td_module.php)
- Class: `td_module` (abstract, many other classes in the parent theme inherit this one)
- Method: `get_author()`
- There are many other classes inheriting td_module in the parent theme, hence I cannot just extend `td_module` in my child theme since every change to the parent theme would be lost when the theme gets updated

Somehow I need to expand this method to show something different, but **I don't want to change the method in the `td_module` class: even when it would be the fastest / most secure solution, this code would be overwritten on every theme upgrade**.

This method is widely used in the Theme, that's why is that important to add some code here.

Why I still have some hope: There is a WP filter `td_wp_booster_module_constructor`, being called on the constructor of td_module class. The problem is that this class doesn't have any other filter on the method for showing the authors, but just the `td_wp_booster_module_constructor` filter call on the constructor.
The base PHP (and OOP) question: is it possible to expand / replace a method by using this filter in the constructor somehow?

Some code to clarify:

```
abstract class td_module {
    ...
    function __construct($post, $module_atts = array()) {
        ...
        // Can I change the get_author behavior by using this filter?
        apply_filters("td_wp_booster_module_constructor", $this, $post);
        // This is the only filter available in the entire class!
        ...    
    }
    ...

    function get_author() {
        $buffy = '';
        // Code for generating author link ($buffy .= ...)
        ...
        // This function doesn't have any apply_filter, there are no filters available
        return $buffy;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you extend the `td_module` class in the child theme and override the `get_author()` function in it?

Comment: Because there are many other classes already inheriting td_module in the parent theme. This is clarified in the scenario description.

Comment: So? You should still be able to extend with a different class with a different method body, no? The other code will use the other class so be unaffected?

Comment: @delboy1978uk that's the issue, I want to affect that method everywhere, even in the inheriting classes. This method is widely used, I need to change it in a way it impacts everywhere

Comment: Ah. In that case, extend the parent class with a new class with this new method. Then just change what your old classes extend. `Base Class -> New Class with new method -> All child classes`

Comment: @delboy1978uk child classes are also part of the parent theme. These changes would be also lost when the theme gets updated :)

Comment: urgh, so my answer below won't work then?

Comment: @delboy1978ukr right, it won't work

Comment: In this case, I would suggest you add your own function based on the parent theme function in the child theme functions.php and change as per your needs and use it.

Comment: @Shifrin please read the scenario once again... there are many classes in the parent theme already using td_module, I cannot rewrite them all and every change I do on the parent theme would be lost when updating

Comment: @yivi yes, thanks for your answer! I guess you have really understood the scenario. Will give Runkit a try when having some time and will get back to you, your answer seems to be the better one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, **you can't modify a class definition at runtime**. The fact that you have a filter available on the constructor is a red herring and really not relevant.

Either the `get_author()` has some facility to change it's behaviour from outside class definition (in Wordpress parlance, filter and action hooks), or you **simply cannot do it**.

Outside of Wordpress, in an application with a proper dependency inversion container, you should probably do this by [decorating the class](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Structural/Decorator/README.html) and having all class consumer use the decorated class.

But since you have no way of telling class consumers to use one or the other, and a lot of code out of your control is presumably instantiating the class directly, something like this simply won't fly.

---

There is one extension, [Runkit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php), that allows for changes of behaviour and definitions at runtime. there is even a method to [modify a method definition](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-method-redefine.php).  although I have not tried the extension, and do not know if it runs in an updated PHP runtime.

**Note it is almost certainly a very bad idea to do this on production code**, and that since you are dealing with code out of your control anyway you can't even be sure you would be changing the definition before it's used for the first time.

I've also found [a repo for Runkit](https://github.com/runkit7/runkit7) that says that it *almost* works on PHP 7, if you are absolutely convinced on going that way.

Comment: It was quite difficult to have it installed but at the end it worked! And yes, I take your recommendation: I will not use this code on a productive environment. At the end, I just needed to know either if there is a way for doing that or not. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that the base class is vendor code which you did not write.

So create a class in between your classes extending it!

Job done!

```
<?php

class SomeWordpressCrap
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        return 'something';
    }
}

class YourAwesomeNewClass extends SomeWordpressCrap
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        return 'something better!';
    }
}

class OneOfYourExistingClasses extends YourAwesomeNewClass
{

}
```

> UPDATE So it turns out the `OneOfYourExistingClasses` is also vendor code, so the above solution will not work.

However! You could use Roave's "Better Reflection" lib, which you can find here https://github.com/Roave/BetterReflection

This will allow you to "Change the body of a function or method to do something different", which I believe is exactly what you need. Good luck!

Comment: As said above, this solution won't work since I cannot make the classes in the parent theme to inherit now from another class. This code would be lost when updating the parent theme.

Comment: Please check out my updated answer, I think I found a solution that might work for you!

Comment: The approach is good, I've tested it. Unfortunately, all the classes are already loaded in memory on WordPress, hence by a PHP restriction it cannot overwrite the in-memory class.

Comment: sounds like you've outgrown your theme.